# Generate nested array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I wrote a method to generate nested array from an array of keys.

```
public static function generateSubArray(array $keys)
{
    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        if(!isset($subArray[$key])){
            $subArray[$key] = [];
        }
        $subArray = $subArray[$key];
    }
    return $subArray;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ret = Utils::generateSubArray(['name', 'id', 'fix']);
var_dump($ret);
```

Expected:

```
$ret = [
         'name' => 
             [
                'id' => ['fix']
             ]
       ]
```

But get as empty array. What's wrong???

Comment: You overwrite your array every loop: `$subArray = $subArray[$key];` so at the end you will end up with an empty array.

Comment: What is your expected output. Post that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
public static function generateSubArray(array $keys)
{
    $subArray = [];
    $parent =& $subArray;

    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        if(!isset($parent[$key])){
            $parent[$key] = [];
        }
        $parent =& $parent[$key];
    }
    return $subArray;
}
```

Comment: In your code you we're replacing $subArray on every iteration. I'm using $parent as a pointer to the current $subArray node. @6yt9Bka